# Additional Attributes sequelize pivot n:m

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I Have Many To Many Relation set as in my case model

```
Case.associate = function (models) {
    Case.belongsToMany(models.ranger, {
        through: 'case_rangers',
        foreignKey: 'caseId',
        otherKey: 'rangerId',
        as: 'assignee',
        timestamps: false,
        scope: {
            status: 'ASSIGNED'
        }
    });

};
```

Now, i am trying to add an assignee in a case, which is failing to store additional column in pivot table
Query

```
Case.findByPk(2).then((caseId2) => {
    ranger.findByPk(1).then((helper) => {
        caseId2.setAssignee(helper, {eta: "1 hr" });
    })
});
```

In My case, eta is storing null

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation of `set` in n:m relation, the second parameter is `options` and in order to set additional attributes you need to pass `options.through` so you should call:

`caseId2.setAssignee(helper, { through: { eta: "1 hr" } });`.

Documentation: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html#instance-method-set

**EDIT:**
In order to add new `assignee` the the `caseId2` you should use the `addAssignee` method with additional attributes:

`caseId2.addAssignee(helper, { through: { eta: '1 hr' } });`

That should create new association between `caseId2` and `helper` together with additional relation data specified by `through` parameter.

Comment: set is used to update the assignee that was stored previously.
with your query, it will set eta to 1 hr of all assignee of that case.

Comment: @RanjanAdhikari From the documentation of set: "Set the associated models by passing an array of instances or their primary keys. Everything that it not in the passed array will be un-associated.". You should perform different operation if you want to update the relation data, or form your question better before downvoting the answers.